# Join between plasterboard and hardwall?

Tags: drywall, plaster

We are building a fake chimney breast in our living room and I have built the bottom half out of brick and the top half will be stud wall with plasterboard.

I will be using a Thistle Hard wall backing coat on the bricks before I skim with Thistle Multi-finish. The top half will be built from studs and plasterboard then plastered, as we are having an inset TV. Only the front and outer sides will be plastered. The fireplace inside is brick slips/brick thins.

My question is what type of join shall I do between the hardwall section and the plasterboard section?

My concern is that cracks may develop at this point and not sure that mesh tape is strong enough.

I have attached a photo with a rough outline of the stud work/plasterboard that will be built on top. With the yellow line the area where I have a concern.

[image: Fireplace side join]

Comment: Wait, you're skim-coating the brick so they won't be visible at all? What was the point of doing all the hard work of putting in brick in the first place, then? Or am I totally misunderstanding the first sentence of your 2nd paragraph means?

Comment: As there is a wood burner being put here, there cannot be any combustibles within 350mm. The mantle is further than this, so can be wood, and the walls/bricks are less than this, so must be brick & render. So the lower half has to be built from brick.